# Hibernate Mapping: How do I create/design a bidirectional relationship ENTITY?

Tags: spring, hibernate, database-design, erd

### Problem statement

Assume you have report with an attribute call status
but each status change needs to be recorded and by which user.
So you will most likely end up with

```
REPORT
REPORT_ID

REPORT_STATUS
STATUS_ID
REPORT_ID
```

but how should I get the current status without "caculation" (ie get last modified date)

I come up with this solution

```
REPORT
REPORT_ID
CURRENT_STATUS_ID

REPORT_STATUS
STATUS_ID
REPORT_ID
```

Assume there are more attributes you need, I suspect this way of creating a table have some issues with hibernate when it try to `CREATE REPORT` then try to `CREATE STATUS`.

I just tried to created the hibernate mapping using annotation for this relationship.
Everyone I tried to save.. I get

> STATUS_REPORT_PK parent key not found

It means that when is trying to create report status, the report is not created yet.

How do I do a proper mapping that allows me to commit both at the same time

Comment: Why do you suspect that? This seems perfectly legitimate?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha I cannot seems to map this out, please help

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a logical inconsistency here

Lets say we need to generate a report. Now the report_id is stored but we need a status ID.

But to get a new status we need to specify a report. Since the report is not created the status can't be created and vice versa.

I'm assuming there are a limited number of status's so lets store them in a table called STATUS

```
REPORT
REPORT_ID
CURRENT_STATUS_ID

REPORT_STATUS
STATUS_ID
REPORT_ID

STATUS
STATUS_ID
```

First create a new report and attach an object of status to it.
Then create an object of REPORT_STATUS

Just in case you've set a cascade type remove it. Hibernate gets confused sometimes.

**EDIT**

You seem to be confused over the tables

The report table will hold the report id, data about the report as well as its current status

The report_status table will hold all the previous status's of the report as well as the current one represented as a composite primary key of status_id and report_id

The status table will hold ALL the possible status's a report can have.
For eg. If the possible status's are  "On Hold","In production", "Released", "editing" , these will be stored in the status table.

The other 2 tables will reference this for the status they are referring to.

Comment: I assume report has no CURRENT_STATUS_ID anymore?

Comment: i think there is a confusion.. the REPORT_STATUS actually holds all the status change... that is why it as a report_id in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251589/how-do-i-map-this-relationship-a-customer-had-many-previous-address-but-only-1

I think this question describe my problem better